# How to load caption content of Fancybox with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, fancybox-3

I want to show some Infos as HTML in the Caption of a Fancybox.

These information are loaded beside the Image as an HTML element with ajax.

Until now I had an afterload method which loaded the caption content from this HTML Element into the caption by detaching it and append it into the caption after the ajax was loaded.

```
afterLoad : function (instance, slide) {
                 $( ".fancybox-slide--current .caption-content" ).detach()
                 .appendTo( ".fancybox-caption" );
            }
```

This is the workaround I used, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Your question is completely incomprehensible.

Comment: Tried to clarify that, I hope this is more understandable. @Janis

Comment: Sorry, I just do not understand. The title says "How to load caption content of Fancybox with Ajax?" but then you talk about detaching - why? Why would you need that?

Comment: Yes your right the Title is missleading..

I need to do that in order to add it the content the fancybox-caption. If I do not do that this Content remains inside the HTML with the image. I detach it from the HTML element and append it to the fancybox-caption.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you, but I guess you are looking for a way to correctly update the caption. Here is a demo, you can tweak it to use ajax:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({

  afterLoad: function(instance, current) {

    if (instance.group[ current.index ].isProcessed !== true ) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        if ( !instance.isClosing ) {
          var caption = 'Another caption for #' + (current.index + 1);

          // Set caption permanently for current group item
          instance.group[ current.index ].opts.caption = caption;

          // Set caption for current slide object
          current.opts.caption = caption;

          // Update caption HTML element
          instance.updateControls();

          // Do this only once
          instance.group[ current.index ].isProcessed = true;
        }

      }, 3000);
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyGZZE?editors=1010